# AWS Insights nest query?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I need to extract some data from Cloud Watch logs and are using Insights and in need of some help. Today, I have this query:

```
stats count() by path  | sort viewCount desc | filter ispresent(eventType)
```

My Cloud watch log contains entries that represent content views. So everytime my lambda is executed it will add a new log entry. So 3 log entries would result in 3 views. When I run the query above, I get the following result:

```
#,  path,  count()
1,  /help  22
2,  /faq   3
...
```

Now I also need a new column, lastViewedDate;

```
#,  path,  count()  lastViewedDate
1,  /help  22       15 Sep
2,  /faq   3        28 Sep
...
```

Is it possible to modify my current query to also show the timestamp of the last log it aggregated somehow? Or do I have to write a another query for that?
'
Managed to solve it by adding

```
| fields  max(@ingestionTime)
```